# Batch Get TV programme name from .TS file

Tags: vlc, dvb, mediainfo

Is there a way to get the Name of current playing program, from a **DVB** recording in **.TS** format?

In **VLC** I can see it in Tile Bar, and also in "Now Playing", but in MediaInfo it shows many hours and programs, and not only what is being played.

Is it possible to get that Title from **VLC CLI**, and pass it to a var from a **BATCH** file?

I use **Mediainfo CLI** to pass others parameters, but if I look for it in the "Menu" section:

```
%mediainfo% "%~1" "--Inform=Menu; %%Title%%"
```

nothing shows, and I can't find the right parameter to get the Title of the TV Show (although maybe it will show all the hours and programs and not the current).

So, I'd like to know if I can do it with **VLC CLI**, **MediaInfo CLI**, or another **CLI** software.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have recorded a TV stream there must be [DVB tables](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_EN/300400_300499/300468/01.03.01_60/en_300468v010301p.pdf) in it.
The information you want is hidden in these tables:

- [SDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Description_Table): Service Description Table (~ channel description: scrambled/clear, status, ...)
- EIT: Event Information Table (~ program description: name, length, ...)

Both of these tables are used to build an [EPG](http://www.keysight.com/upload/cmc_upload/All/6C06MPEGPAPER1.pdf).

Unfortunately I don't know a direct way to achieve what you want but you might want to try `libdvbpsi`, `ffmpeg` or `dvbsnoop` : this tools can analyse, and extract information from TS files.